# Maven :How to use local archiva repository in project?

Tags: maven, archiva

Downloaded  **Apache Archiva** and uploaded 10 Jar file on it now i want to use this Archiva repository in my **pom.xml** so these 10 jar download from the **Archiva** ..What all setting i have to do i made changes in my **pom.xml** file like below

```
<repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://serverip:8888/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Also added all jar in pom.xml file

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.forum</groupId>
            <artifactId>jforum</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imaging</groupId>
            <artifactId>imaging</artifactId>
            <version>01012005</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

But i am getting

```
Missing artifact org.jbosscaches:jboss-transaction-api:jar:1.0.1.GA
```

What all i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes it worked now

```
  <url>http://ipaddress:8888/repository/internal/</url>
```

Comment: The Archiva 2.0 release changed the default deployment location to / instead of /archiva, so examples you find from 1.x might need to be adjusted. If any of them happen to be in the Archiva documentation, please file a bug report.